# Ms Access VBA if condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 4 text boxes on a ms access form and i am running following code but it is not working correctly:

```
If Text1.value = 1 then
    Me.Text2.Enabled = True
    Me.Text3.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Text2.Enabled = False
    Me.Text3.Enabled = False
End if
If Text1.value = 2 then
    Me.text2.Enabled = True
    Me.Text4.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Text2.Enabled = False
    Me.Text4.Enabled = False
End if
```

Comment: "Not working" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? I see only 3 textboxes.

Comment: And Text2 is repeated in the first Else.

Comment: no its not repeating its typo, text2 is repeating in both if conditions

Comment: Still see only 3 textboxes. Should there be a different one in the second If block?

Comment: Code updated in original post

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set Enabled property independently for each record on Continuous or Datasheet form, VBA will not work. Must use Conditional Formatting.

If this is a Single View form, VBA in form Current and Text1 AfterUpdate events. Consider simpler code:

```
Me.Text2.Enabled = (Me.Text1 = 1 Or Me.Text1 = 2)
Me.Text3.Enabled = Me.Text1 = 1
Me.Text4.Enabled = Me.Text1 = 2
```

However, could still use Conditional Formatting and avoid VBA entirely.

Comment: thanks for the answer , it is single form. Can i get example of conditional formating

Comment: Search web for tutorials. This one looks good https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_formatting.htm